# Predicting of Randomforest model

Tags: r, output, raster, random-forest, predict

I implemented random forest and then started predicting Leaf area index in a forest using 10 variables.But when predicting stops, the output of the prediction is an empty map with null values. I appreciate if someone help me with that. I add here the code that I am running.

Here in the first step, I assign zero to NA values in the rasters.

```
tex37$glcm_variance_ENVI[is.na(tex37$glcm_variance_ENVI)] <- 0
tex37$glcm_entropy[is.na(tex37$glcm_entropy)] <- 0
RVI_raster3$glcm_mean_ENVI[is.na(RVI_raster3$glcm_mean_ENVI)] <- 0
RVI_raster3$glcm_mean[is.na(RVI_raster3$glcm_mean)] <- 0
RVI_raster3$glcm_variance[is.na(RVI_raster3$glcm_variance)] <- 0
RVI_raster5$glcm_mean_ENVI[is.na(RVI_raster5$glcm_mean_ENVI)] <- 0
RVI_raster5$glcm_variance[is.na(RVI_raster5$glcm_variance)] <- 0
RVI_raster5$glcm_mean[is.na(RVI_raster5$glcm_mean)] <- 0
RVI_raster7$glcm_mean_ENVI[is.na(RVI_raster7$glcm_mean_ENVI)] <- 0
RVIrededge[is.na(RVIrededge)] <- 0
```

Here I stack all my 10 raster layers in one raster.

```
image_stack_imp = stack(tex37$glcm_variance_ENVI,
                     tex37$glcm_entropy,
                     RVI_raster3$glcm_mean_ENVI,
                     RVI_raster3$glcm_mean,
                     RVI_raster3$glcm_variance,
                     RVI_raster5$glcm_mean_ENVI,
                     RVI_raster5$glcm_variance,
                     RVI_raster5$glcm_mean,
                     RVI_raster7$glcm_mean_ENVI,
                     RVIrededge)
```

I made a table from my feature, plus Leaf area index as label.

```
Table_Importance = data.frame(LAI=d$LAI,
                          tex37.glcm_variance_ENVI=LAI37$glcm_variance_ENVI,
                          tex37.glcm_entropy=LAI37$glcm_entropy,
                          RVI_raster3.glcm_mean_ENVI=RVI3$glcm_mean_ENVI,
                          RVI_raster3.glcm_variance=RVI3$glcm_variance,
                          RVI_raster3.glcm_mean=RVI3$glcm_mean,
                          RVI_raster5.glcm_variance=RVI5$glcm_variance,
                          RVI_raster5.glcm_mean_ENVI=RVI5$glcm_mean_ENVI,
                          RVI_raster5.glcm_mean=RVI5$glcm_mean,
                          RVI_raster7.glcm_mean_ENVI=RVI7$glcm_mean_ENVI,
                          RVIrededge_values)
```

And finally running Randomforest:

```
set.seed(104)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(Table_Importance), replace = 1, prob=c(0.66,0.33))
rf_imp<- randomForest(LAI ~ ., data=Table_Importance[ind ==     1,],importance=TRUE, ntree=1000, mtry=3)
pred_imp <- predict(rf_imp, Table_Importance[ind == 2,])
rmse(Table_Importance[ind==2, "LAI"], pred_imp)
###############################predicting########################
Map_LAI = predict(image_stack_imp, rf_imp,na.rm = TRUE, progress='window', type ='response')
plot(Map_LAI)
```

Here is the small sample:

```
(head(Table_Importance, 20)
```

Comment: Can you provide a (small) reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow and I do not know exactly how can I do that? because for each variable, there are different commands which take time to run. which part of the code is better to be uploaded here?

Comment: dput(head(Table_Importance, 20)) will give us the first 20 rows of your Table_Importance. That is what goes into the Randomforest. But first check if you are not getting any errors from the predict function and if the data in the Table_Importance is what you expect it to be. No NA's, only zeroes, etc.

Comment: I checked for the NA values, the table doesn't have any of it. The error of predict function was due to the NA values in my image and I replace them with zero as I showed before. I added the sample of my table.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem myself, :D
the answer is only that the name of the table attributes should be the same as the name of the training table. In my case the attribute names are as follow:

```
Table_Importance = data.frame(LAI=d$LAI,
                          glcm_variance_ENVI=LAI37$glcm_variance_ENVI,
                          glcm_entropy=LAI37$glcm_entropy,
                          glcm_mean_ENVI.1=RVI3$glcm_mean_ENVI,
                          glcm_variance.1=RVI3$glcm_variance,
                          glcm_mean.1=RVI3$glcm_mean,
                          glcm_variance.2=RVI5$glcm_variance,
                          glcm_mean_ENVI.2=RVI5$glcm_mean_ENVI,
                          glcm_mean.2=RVI5$glcm_mean,
                          glcm_mean_ENVI.3=RVI7$glcm_mean_ENVI,
                          layer=RVIrededge_values)
```